# Cluster Cassandra + Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra

**Issue Description and Context :**

I am operating a 3-node cluster, with each node hosting both Cassandra and Elasticsearch services. The version of Cassandra is 4.1.1 and the version of Elasticsearch is 7.11.1 on the 3 nodes. All nodes are interconnected on the same network.

**Encountered Issue :**

I have encountered the following error from Cassandra

> Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency QUORUM (2 replica were required but only 1 acknowledged the write)

**Investigation Findings :**

Upon investigation, I observed that the Elasticsearch index files were present on only two of the three nodes, implying a node did not contain the index files.

In light of this, and after consulting the Elasticsearch documentation, I discerned that for a 3-node cluster, it is recommended to adjust the replica setting to 2, ensuring the index data is stored on each node.

**Considering these configurations :**

Is this configuration optimal and reliable for a 3-node cluster ?
Can I anticipate that the modification on the Elasticsearch side will alleviate the aforementioned Cassandra error ?

Thank you

**Implemented Changes :**

- Elasticsearch: Modified the replica setting to 2, confirming index files are now present on all 3 nodes.
- Cassandra: Retained the replication configuration at 3, ensuring data is replicated across all nodes.